# Flowdocument Table Cell Background issue

Tags: xaml, flowdocument

Wanted to set background image of TableCell in

```
<TableCell ColumnSpan="1" Background="{$Sign}">
    <Paragraph >
        <Figure HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" >
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <Image Source="{$tickmark}"></Image>
            </BlockUIContainer>
        </Figure>
    </Paragraph>
</TableCell>
```

When I try to parse it an exception occurs

> XAMParserException:- failure to create background from text "C:\Users\Home\abcd.png"

`{$Sign}` is a variable defined at top of xslt which contains the path.

I've also tried writing the complete path rather than writing `{$Sign}`.

Kindly help. Please explain how to set background image of a cell in flowdocument.

Comment: There is no XSLT here.

Comment: By mistake I've written it. It is a flow document in which we're creating

Comment: If it's not about XSLT remove the tag, change the title and edit your question.

Comment: I'm able to make background using <Sectio.background>. But the problem is that the background of the image remains till the first paragraph. Like if we have <TableCell><Section><Section.background></Section.background><Paragraph>1</Paragraph><Paragraph>2</Paragraph></Section><TableCell>. In this case image comes behind para 1 only not on para 2.